# Given that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x) =1$ , Prove that f is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given that $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that[image]$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x) =1$, Prove that f is unbounded. 
Here is the proof I am thinking of. Please see if there is some mistake, If there is please help me with a better proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) =1$, there is one large enough $M$ such that, whenever $x\geq M$ we have $f'(x)>\frac{1}{2}$, which means that $f(x) \geq f(M)+\frac{x-M}{2}$ (for $x>M$). Since $\frac{x-M}{2}$ is unbounded so must be $f$.

Comment: Thanks , Very nice solution .

Comment: You're welcome. I think that Calculus is very powerful because it allows you to treat very difficult functions as linear functions, and that is just what I did.